# fn key sometime activated by itself on my asus

Tags: laptop, keyboard, asus-laptop

i dont know if it is about hardware or software, my fn key sometimes activated by itself. it has been happening after i uninstalled xdm on my ubuntu (or maybe it is just coincidence) but i already tried switch the os using windows but i got the same thing. my laptop is asus x455l.

the errors:

- i can switch to another app in unity launcher but i can't click any buttons inside of the app.
- activate keyboard to another language.
- saving file when i click link on the browser instead opening it.

in a nutshell, the keyboard is not functioning at all and i can't use it for work. since when i press A, it opens menu of app instead.

is this true about fn or something else ? how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

A quick internet search found this thread on [Tom's Guide](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2377769/reverse-function-key-settings-press.html) that suggests that <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> should toggle fn lock.

This *apparently* might not work on newer models and doesn't seem to be documented in the manual.

Comment: i have tried google it before but none of them are working and I am still not sure if it is config issue or hardware broken, it is fn or the super key who is acting strange (because I dont remember the shortcuts for each function) . currently i disable super key from any shortcut but still too early to decide it is working. if the error keep going then i try that tom's guide.